# Getting user country in swift

Tags: swift, google-maps, country-codes

I am trying to get users country to help supporting good user experience in my program, is there any code to get the current location of a certain user in swift language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Local.current` variable to get information on your user such as region code: `Local.current.regionCode`, language code: `Locale.current.languageCode` etc.

This is done without getting the specific location of the user and rather gets the information from the device settings.

Comment: This will return the user preference, not its actual location

Comment: @LeoDabus are you just trying to get the users current location? Like `CLLocation`?

Comment: I mean the user can set the device locale preference to anywhere. Btw I am not the OP